# Xquartz problem for OS 10.14

Tags: macos, terminal, display, mojave, xquartz

Recently upgraded to Mojave (10.14) and I'm having a problem creating X apps from the terminal.

OSX 10.14.6
XQuartz 2.7.11 (xorg-server 1.18.4)

[08:44][{501}]% printenv DISPLAY
/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.fBkW7BwtJl/org.macports:0

If I switch the X and open a terminal window from the 'Applications' menu I get an xterm window and its display variable is set to :0. However, when I try to open any X application from the Apple Terminal window, which has the display listed above, the application hangs without producing any output or any window and I have to kill it.

This is a pain for me because I routinely run IDL (a programming and display language) from within an Emacs buffer (the MacPorts version, which uses  the native MacOS windowing system), which requires a connection to the X system for displaying plots.

The work around is to launch Xquartz and then an Xterm from it, then launch Emacs.app from that.

But I'd rather have a more native solution.

Any suggestions?
TIA